# Extract 2 fields from string with search

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix, awk, sed

I have a file with several lines of data.  The fields are not always in the same position/column.  I want to search for 2 strings and then show only the field and the data that follows.  For example:

```
{"id":"1111","name":"2222","versionCurrent":"3333","hwVersion":"4444"}

{"id":"5555","name":"6666","hwVersion":"7777"}
```

**I would like to return the following:**

```
"id":"1111","hwVersion":"4444"

"id":"5555","hwVersion":"7777"
```

I am struggling because the data isn't always in the same position, so I can't chose a column number.  I feel I need to search for `"id"` and `"hwVersion"`  Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: For parsing json use json aware tools. Use `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data looks like a mapping objects and even corresponding to a JSON format, something like this should do, if you don't mind using Python (which comes with JSON) support:

```py
import json

def get_id_hw(s):
    d = json.loads(s)
    return '"id":"{}","hwVersion":"{}"'.format(d["id"], d["hwVersion"])
```

We take a line of input string into `s` and parse it as JSON into a dictionary `d`. Then we return a formatted string with double-quoted `id` and `hwVersion` strings followed by column and double-quoted value of corresponding key from the previously obtained `dict`.

We can try this with these test input strings and prints:

```py
# These will be our test inputs.
s1 = '{"id":"1111","name":"2222","versionCurrent":"3333","hwVersion":"4444"}'
s2 = '{"id":"5555","name":"6666","hwVersion":"7777"}'

# we pass and print them here
print(get_id_hw(s1))
print(get_id_hw(s2))
```

But we can just as well iterate over lines of any input.

If you really wanted to use `awk`, you could, but it's not the most robust and suitable tool:

```
awk '{ i = gensub(/.*"id":"([0-9]+)".*/, "\\1", "g")
       h = gensub(/.*"id":"([0-9]+)".*/, "\\1", "g")
       printf("\"id\":\"%s\",\"hwVersion\":\"%s\"\n"), i, h}' /your/file
```

Since you mention position is not known and assuming it can be in any order, we use one regex to extract `id` and the other to get `hwVersion`, then we print it out in given format. If the values could be something other then decimal digits as in your example, the `[0-9]+` but would need to reflect that.

And for the fun if it (this preserves the order) if entries from the file, in `sed`:

```
sed -e 's#.*\("\(id\|hwVersion\)":"[0-9]\+"\).*\("\(id\|hwVersion\)":"[0-9]\+"\).*#\1,\3#' file
```

It looks for two groups  of `"id"` or `"hwVersion"` followed by `:"<DECIMAL_DIGITS>"`.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with @KamilCuk. More specifically

```
jq -c '{id: .id, hwVersion: .hwVersion}' <<< '{"id":"1111","name":"2222","versionCurrent":"3333","hwVersion":"4444"}'
```

Outputs:

```
{"id":"1111","hwVersion":"4444"}
```

Not quite the specified output, but valid JSON

More to the point, your input should probably be processed record by record, and my guess is that a two column output with "id" and "hwVersion" would be even easier to parse:

```
cat << EOF | jq -j '"\(.id)\t\(.hwVersion)\n"'
{"id":"1111","name":"2222","versionCurrent":"3333","hwVersion":"4444"}
{"id":"5555","name":"6666","hwVersion":"7777"}
EOF
```

Outputs:

```
1111    4444
5555    7777
```